# Editing Map Series 'Page with Count' Dynamic Text

Tags: arcgis-pro, layouts, dynamic-text, map-series

Does anyone know how to change the 'Page with Count' Map Series function, from '1 of 13' to '001_013'?

When I click the 'Text View' icon, I am not what sure what I should edit "page" to?

Comment: Not sure you can achieve that, [this](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/layouts/add-and-modify-dynamic-text.htm) appears to be the range of options for dynamic text. May be you suggest it as an idea on the esri ideas website?

Comment: If the map series is spatial series (based on a layer), then you could add an attribute to the layer and add the values (calculate the values) into that attribute for each feature.  Then you could use the Map Series attribute dynamic text, instead of the page count dynamic text.  Of course, this would break if you add/remove or re-order any features in that layer.